# Feasibility of transplanting a mature rose

Tags: plant-care, transplanting, roses

This rose is in the way, and I would like to move it about 20 feet back and towards the fence in the next week or two. It's about 6 feet tall; the largest stem is about two inches in diameter at the base. I don't know the specific species or anything else about it.
[image]

The plant was here when I bought the place 18 months ago, and I have not done any kind of maintenance on it (if that's not obvious). I wouldn't be sad to just remove it, but:

**Would it be feasible to transplant without too much effort? If so, what techniques would give the best chance of success?**

I'm in the Seattle area, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cut it hard back, just above buds, to about 30cm off the ground. Prepare a nice big planting hole where you want to put it. Dig it up carefully keeping as much of the root system soil in place as possible. Replant it immediately and backfill to the original soil level on the rose. Water well and water as necessary throughout the first season until it's established. And keep the surrounding area (say a one metre wide circle around the rose) weed and grass free, permanently.